# Python# select download link BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

is there a way to select a certain "link", in a list of links es: link1 - link2 - link3 in a web page and "click" on it thus downloading the content of that link only?

I would like to select "MAX" and once after selected download the content of "donwload data"

I have already created a program using selenium but it is too slow for the number of downloads I have to run

I put a link to the web page from which I want to extract the data:

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/clvs/historical

Answer (score 0):

Just use the api on the backend and play around with the dates and limit. I changed the limit to 10000 (defaults to just 18). Then manage the json response however you wish. You don't need BeautifulSoup to do this, just requests()

```
https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/CLVS/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2012-01-17&limit=10000&todate=2022-01-17
```